# "Key is duplicated" error in yaml when used in if-else statement

Tags: java, intellij-idea, kubernetes, yaml

I'm using an if-else statement inside my **deployment.yaml** to determine which key to use from my **values.yaml** file, in the following way:

```
{{ - if .Values.some_key}}
          some_key:
{{ toYaml .Values.some_key| indent 12 }}
{{ else if .Values.global.some_key}}
          some_key:
{{ toYaml .Values.global.some_key| indent 12 }}
{{ - end }}
```

I got a "Key 'some_key' is duplicated" error from IntelliJ, and was wondering what is the correct way of using the condition in this situation.

Comment: Is this in the context of a Helm chart (it should be in a directory named `templates`)?  Does IntelliJ know that?

Comment: Thanks David, installing the Go Template and the Kubernetes plugins for Intellij removed the error.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to remove IntelliJ's errors by installing the Go Template plugin and the Kubernetes plugin for Intellij.